# Anyway to use someone else's neovim/vim keybindings config on VS Code

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code, config, key-bindings

I have just migrated from Atom, there, I was using Vim-plus but now on VS Code I have switched to neovim, but the problem is, there are many conflicting keybindings.

I tried to change them manually (something like, to close editor, 'Ctrl+c+t', which I mapped to close editor's tab, similarly others).

But I feel that's very unproductive and also can cause strain in my fingers. So any suggestions, or keybindings config of anyone which I can use alongside the NeoVim to increase my productivity. Or any other suggestions how to properly configure my VS Code?

NOTE: I know about the existence of an Atom Keybindings Extension which I honestly don't care, as I was mainly using Vim keybindings there and never bother to learn atom specific keybindings.

Answer (score 0):

If you want VS Code to act like **VIM**, which is super unique in its interface and keybindings, there is an extension called:

### VSCode Vim

###### VSCode Vim's Marketplace ID: `vscodevim.vim`

---

Personally I can't stand the VIM keybindings, so I don't know how great the extension is, but I know people who use it. It has 2.4 million downloads and counting. I also know, because of my buddy, that its not perfect, but it's close.

As with any other extension, don't just install it and hope it's what you wanted "out-of-the-box", this theme is customizable, and requires you to configure it. Make sure you read the `README.md`, and set it up so you know that it is best suited for your expectations.

If you are already using the VSCode VIM Extension, and you find that you are having conflicting issues using the keybindings associated with it. You can troubleshoot them using the keybindings troubleshooting tool by selecting it from the quick input menu.

1. ###### Press <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. ###### Type the phrase: "Keyboard Shortcut Troubleshooting"
3. ###### Select the option "DEVELOPER: Toggle Keyboard Shortcut Troubleshooting Tool"

The tool should open in the console below. The menu might look like gibberish at first, however; the output of the newly opened console should make more sense once you use a familiar keybinding. Make sure that the console window is scrolled to the bottom and opened wide enough so your able to read everything logged. The tool will tell you what is attached to the keybinding your using, so you can see any conflicts that are happening, and what the key is set to do by you, by extensions, and by default.

###### Make changes to your keybindings.json file as necessary.

Comment: I'm using NeoVim extension, my problem was, **there were many conflicting keybindings of NeoVim with VS Code itself,** seems like I have to manually take care of them.

Comment: Use the troubleshooting tool